# Regex: until first occurrence. If no occurence match string

Tags: regex

I'm using this regex ".+?(?=\s*//)" to match everything before //.

How do I tell regex to also match the string if it doesn't even contain //

In other words: I want to delete everything after // if it even exists.

Thanks

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/5TruEv/2) work? `^(.*?)(//.*)?$`

Comment: You will get more accurate regexes if you specify the flavor of the regex.

Comment: @jhnc good point... I hadn't considered the case of multiple `//` in the string. Deleted

Comment: [`^(?:(?!\s*//).)*`](https://regex101.com/r/vbqCrL/1)

Comment: You could match `//.*$` and replace with an empty string https://regex101.com/r/DCQJty/1